# How to get active tab's value in variable of javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have multiple tabs in li and each li contains class and id.And each tab has its own div which contains kind of some form.

```
<ul>                                        
<a href="#"><li id="call_details" class="postliactive">Driver Details</li></a
<a href="#"><li id="call_add"class="postli" >Address</li></a>
<a href="#"><li id="call_screen"class="postli">Screening</li></a>
<a href="#"><li id="call_license" class="postli">License Info</li></a>
<a href="#"><li id="call_traininginfo"class="postli">Training Info</li></a>
<a href="#"><li id="call_attachment"class="postli">Attachment</li></a>
</ul>
```

when i click on other inactive li at that time i want to get value of active tab's value in javascript var. Problem is i am getting [object NodeList] in alert when i am trying to show.
I was saving like this and giving alert as:

javascript:

```
`var driverval =document.getElementsByClassName('.form-horizontal')

    alert("DriverDetailsin driver"+driverval[index]);`
```

where form-horizontal is my class name of div for Driver Details li.

How to get readable value as my var driverval will keeping changing on basis of selected tab.

Answer (score 0):

Use [.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML)

```
alert("DriverDetailsin driver" + driverval[index].innerHTML);
```

---

`driverval[index]` is DOM element so you get alert `[object NodeList]` to get text inside you can use `.innerHTML`

Comment: It showing me blank, even as i put some value in input type text of form whose class is form-horizontal

Comment: @user2696142 if it's input than use `driverval[index].value`

Comment: is it correct of getting var driverval through document.getElementsByClassName('.classname')

Comment: @user2696142 it is correct but you don't need `.` in `.form-horizontal` .Use `document.getElementsByClassName('form-horizontal')`